# Stalk map on fiber products of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes and $x$ a point on $X$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. Recall this induces a map $f_x:\mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}\rightarrow \mathcal O_{X,x}$ on the level of sheaves.

Consider the projection $g:X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_{Y,y}\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{Y,y}$. Let $x'$ be the inverse of $x$ under $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_{Y,y}\rightarrow X$. Why do we have $f_x=g_{x'}$?

This is stated without justification in Liu's book, but I'm having trouble seeing why it is true. I think we can reduce to the case where $X$ and $Y$ are affine. The associated ring map seems to be, if $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $X=\operatorname{Spec} B$,

$$ A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak p} \otimes_A B \cong (A\backslash \mathfrak p)^{-1}B,$$

where we consider $B$ as an $A$-module via the map $\phi: A\rightarrow B$ associated to the map of global sections induced by $f$. I know that the stalk map $X\rightarrow Y$ corresponds to

$$A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow B_{\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)}.$$

So the question now seem to reduce to verifying that $B\backslash \phi^{-1} (\mathfrak p)$ is $\phi^{-1}(A\backslash \mathfrak p)$. And they equal.

But the first map I gave is a map of rings, while the second is a map of stalks. So why do they seem to be the same? I also don't know what $x'$ is in the tensor product or how to make sure it gets sent to the right thing in $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{Y,y}$. I would greatly appreciate any clarification.

(My apologies for yet another elementary question about fiber products. I'm having an absolutely dreadful time learning about them.)

**Addendum.** The proof of the following theorem begins, "By the base change $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{Y,y}\rightarrow Y$, which preserves the local rings in the inequality, we may reduce to $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$, where $A$ is a Noetherian local ring and $y$ is the closed point of $Y$." I suspect this has something to do with my question above. I would appreciate any explanation, especially of the "preserves the local rings" part.

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of locally Noetherian schemes.
>   Let $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$. Then
>
> $$\dim \mathcal O_{X_y,x} \ge \dim \mathcal O_{X,x} - \dim \mathcal
> > O_{Y,y}.$$
>
> If $f$ is flat, then we have equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stalk map for the original $X = Spec B \to Y = Spec A$ is correct, so let's work out the other map.

The $g$ map is $Spec B_p = Spec (A \backslash p)^{-1} B \to Spec A_p$ like you mentioned. If $q = \phi^{-1}(p)$ is your $x$, then your $x'$ corresponds to the ideal $qB_p$ in $B_p$. The stalk map for $g$ then corresponds to $A_p \to (B_p)_{qB_p}$. This is the same as $A_p \to B_q$ map, by going through the isomorphism $B_q \cong (B_p)_{qB_p}$. That this is an isomorphism is Atiyah Macdonald Exercise 3.4. (Write down what you think the isomorphism should be, and check it :) )

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on the part I edited in? I think the same kind of thing works, but I need to go through the details.

Comment: @Potato, yes, it's the same kind of thing. In fact my answer already told you that $O_{X,x}$ and $O_{Y,y}$ are the same before and after the base change. You only need to check that $X_y$ is the same before and after, which follows from some transitivty of fiber product ($X \times_{Y} (Y \times_{Z} W) = X \times_{Z} W$ that kind of thing)